# Refactor with Expression

Tags: c#, refactoring

I need refactor method Test1 and Test2.

First test method where `AddInfo != null`:

```
public List<FileRequest> Test1(long fileId)
{
    return context.FileRequest.Include("AddInfo")
                              .Where(x=>x.FileId = fileId && x.AddInfo != null)
}
```

First test method where `AddInfo == null`:

```
public List<FileRequest> Test2(long fileId)
{
    return context.FileRequest.Include("AddInfo")
                              .Where(x=>x.FileId = fileId && x.AddInfo == null)
}
```

I'm try create generalize method, but can't implement.

```
public List<FileRequest> Test2(long fileId, Expression<Func<AddInfo, bool>> expression)
{
    return context.FileRequest.Include("AddInfo")
                              .Where(x=>x.FileId = fileId && expression)
}
```

How I can refactor my method?

Comment: Presumably that should be an equality check, not assignment, for `FileId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to just use two `Where` calls:

```
public IQueryable<FileRequest> Test2(long fileId, 
    Expression<Func<FileRequest, bool>> predicate)
{
    return context.FileRequest.Include("AddInfo")
        .Where(x=>x.FileId == fileId)
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Servy, If use two Where calls, return count zero. First Where return count zero entities

Comment: @zrabzdn Then you'll get the exact same result if you AND those two predicates together.  `false AND anything` is `false`, not `anything`.

Comment: Sorry, first predicate return false, and second predicate return true

Comment: @zrabzdn Yes, and `false AND true` is `false`, not `true`.  That's the way AND works.